# how to ignore indent error in jslint cli (for node)

Tags: jslint

I am developing some stuff on node.
I really want to ignore all indent related error, but just want to catch critical errors like forgetting var or syntax error that break the code etc.

How should i specify that in jslint (cli) ? 
I have installed jslint via npm.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `white` option to tell JSLint to ignore whitespace formatting errors. You can set these options at the top of individual files with a `jslint` directive:

```
/*jslint white: true */
```

You can find a list of all available options on the [JSLint website](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html).